# how to check falsy with undefined or null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

undefined and null are falsy in javascript but,

```
var n = null;
if(n===false){
console.log('null');
} else{
console.log('has value');
}
```

but it returns 'has value' when tried in console, why not 'null' ?

Comment: because `false != null`

Answer (score 10):

## To solve your problem:

You can use not operator(!):

```
var n = null;
if(!n){ //if n is undefined, null or false
console.log('null');
} else{
console.log('has value');
}
// logs null
```

## To answer your question:

It is considered falsy or truthy for Boolean. So if you use like this:

```
var n = Boolean(null);
if(n===false){
console.log('null');
} else{
console.log('has value');
}
//you'll be logged null
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check for falsy values using

```
var n = null;
if (!n) {
    console.log('null');
} else {
    console.log('has value');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m3XLn/)

---

Or check for truthiness like

```
var n = null;
if (n) { //true if n is truthy
    console.log('has value');
} else {
    console.log('null');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m3XLn/2/)

Answer (score 3):

A value being "falsy" means that the result of **converting** it to a Boolean is `false`:

```
Boolean(null) // false
Boolean(undefined) // false
// but
Boolean("0") // true
```

This is very different from **comparing** it against a Boolean:

```
null == false // not equal, null == true is not equal either
undefined == false // not equal, undefined == true is not equal either
// but
"0" == true // not equal, however, `"0" == false` is equal
```

Since you are using [strict comparison](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6), the case is even simpler: the strict equality comparison operator returns `false` if operands are not of the same data type. `null` is of type Null and `false` is of type Boolean.

But even if you used loose comparison, the [abstract equality algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) defines that only `null` and `undefined` are equal to each other.

---

Depending on what exactly you want to test for, you have a couple of options:

```
if (!value)         // true for all falsy values

if (value == null)  // true for null and undefined

if (value === null) // true for null
```

In general you should always prefer strict comparison because JS' type conversion rules can be surprising. One of the exceptions is comparing a value against `null`, since loose comparison also catches `undefined`.

Comment: finally an actually good answer. Everyone keeps telling him how to use the null in that specific situation instead of explaining the actual problem...

Answer (score 1):

`===` checks for identity - the exact same type and value.  So `null !== false` firstly because they are not the same type, thus will not match when using `===`.

If you just want to check for any falsey value, then check with:

```
if (!n)
```

If you want to specifically check for `null`, then check for `null` like this:

```
if (n === null)
```